# SQL Server: Find duplicates using group by and having count than delete them all but not first

Tags: sql-server, group-by, having-clause

I have to maintain an old MS SQL 2008 database with tons of records. I notice that about 90% are duplicates.

So what is the best way to remove only the duplicates.

I used...

```
SELECT  [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col...], COUNT(*) AS [DuplicateCount]
FROM myTable
GROUP BY  [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col...]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

to find the duplicates but I struggle how to delete all of them but not the first one. I found some hints with using  *TOP*  but not in combination with group by. Sorry but my SQL is too bad for that ;)

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: When I try:
DELETE
FROM [dbo].[Chargenverfolgung] LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(ID) as RowId, [Col1],[Col2..]
   FROM [dbo].[myTable] 
   GROUP BY [Col1],[Col2..]
) as KeepRows ON
  [dbo].[myTable].ID = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL

I get this error:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: SELECT * instead of DELETE is working!?!